# How to subvert typings of external-facing class constructor to test validation code

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have an external/outward facing class. It contains input-validation code for instances where the library is imported into a JS environment (read: an environment that does not support type checking).

I am attempting to write unit tests specific to that validation code.

```
// function-token.ts;

// ...

export default class FunctionToken extends Token {
  constructor(token: IFunctionToken) {
    if (token == null) {
      throw new Error('token must be specified');
    }
    
    // ...

  }
}
```

Currently when I attempt to write a jestjs test for the validation code, the check fails due to typings:

```
// function-token.spec.ts

import FunctionToken from 'function-token';

test('throws an error when token is nullish', function () {
  // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0 - An argument for 'token' was not provided
  expect(() => new FunctionToken()).toThrow();

  // Argument of [undefined|null] is not assignable to IFunctionToken
  expect(() => new FunctionToken(undefined)).toThrow();
  expect(() => new FunctionToken(null)).toThrow();
});
```

**How do I go about writing a test to subvert the type check with jestjs + ts-jest?**

Note: Changing the underlying class's typing does not make sense as the validation is specific to cases where there is no type checking or enforcement.

Comment: constructor(token: IFunctionToken) ... the typing there fails, right?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger Its the part causing the issue. (changing it to nullable just to pass the tests doesn't make sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you'll get the parameterless call, but I think this is redundant because it defaults to undefined anyway. By casting the arguments to `any` you can bypass the parameter typings.

```
expect(() => new FunctionToken(undefined as any)).toThrow();
expect(() => new FunctionToken(null as any)).toThrow();
```

Alternativly you could just add `// @ts-nocheck` in testfiles concerning guard clauses.

Comment: This is a question pretaining to unit testing. The exported class may be called from a JS instance that doesn't enforce typechecking, so I want to unit test the validation code of the input.

Comment: redressed question to be more clear. This question is specific to testing input validation logic existing specifically for cases where type-checking is not enforced.

Comment: @SReject updated the answer accordingly

Comment: While this did not solve my issue, it put me on the path to finding what I needed. In the end I went with `//@ts-expect-error` for each test specific to type-less environments